# How to append global variable for each element in ngfor in angular 4?

Tags: angular, typescript, global-variables, ngfor

I have a global variable **`public right: any = 30;`**

and I want to call this variable uniquely from each element and increment it by 30 in ngfor (looping `People` object):

```js
interface Person {
  name: String,
    title: String,
    content: String,
    image: String,
    rate: String,
    classActive: String,
    active: Boolean
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-testimonials',
  templateUrl: './testimonials.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./testimonials.component.scss']
})
export class TestimonialsComponent {
  people: Person[] = [{
      name: 'Douglas  Pace',
      title: 'Parcelivery Nailed The Efficiency',
      content: 'Since I installed this app, its always help me book every tickets I need like flight, concert, ' +
        'movie or hotel. I don\'t need to install different app for different ticket. The payment is also very easy',
      image: '../../assets/img/profile_pics/profile_pic.jpg',
      rate: '4.5',
      classActive: 'testimonials__selected-visible',
      active: true
    },
    {
      name: 'Naseebullah  Ahmadi',
      title: 'Parcelivery Nailed The Efficiency',
      content: 'Since I installed this app, its always help me book every tickets I need like flight, concert, ' +
        'movie or hotel. I don\'t need to install different app for different ticket. The payment is also very easy',
      image: '../../assets/img/profile_pics/profile_pic.jpg',
      rate: '4.5',
      classActive: '',
      active: false
    },
    {
      name: 'Haseebullah Ahmadi',
      title: 'Parcelivery Nailed The Efficiency',
      content: 'Since I installed this app, its always help me book every tickets I need like flight, concert, ' +
        'movie or hotel. I don\'t need to install different app for different ticket. The payment is also very easy',
      image: '../../assets/img/profile_pics/profile_pic.jpg',
      rate: '4.5',
      classActive: '',
      active: false
    }
  ];
  public right: any = 30;

  constructor() {}
  stackItem(a) {
    console.log(a);
  }

}
```

```html
<div *ngFor="let person of people; let last = last" 
     class="testimonials__card-container"
     #__person
     [ngClass]="{'testimonials__card-container--not-visible': !person.active}" 
     [style.right]="stackItem(__person.right)">
</div>
```

I remember in Angular 2 we could call global variables as an instance for each element in ngfor. But this is not the case in angular4. Is there any other way?

Comment: 1. I am a little confused by what you are trying to achieve. 2. I guess    console.log(a); gives 'indefined...' ?

Comment: What I want is to increment my global variable for every element in the people object by passing an instance of the global variable.

An yes, console.log() prints undefined even though Ive assigned the global variable to 30. @Vega

Comment: __person.right is not a a global variable. right is a global variable and #_person is a template variable

Comment: But how can I use `right` variable as an instance for each element in ngfor? @Vega

Answer (score 0):

```
  <div *ngFor="let person of people; let last = last" 
       class="testimonials__card-container"
       #__person
       [ngClass]="{'testimonials__card-container--not-visible': !person.active}" 
       [style.right]="stackItem()">
  </div>
       ---------------- 
  stackItem() {
       this.right = this.right + 30;
       return this.right;
  }
```

Comment: I couldve done that aswell. But Im still calling the global variable without creating an instance. I want to be able to somehow make right unique to each item in the object

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me:

```
<div *ngFor="let person of people; let last = last" 
     class="testimonials__card-container"
     #__person
     [ngClass]="{'testimonials__card-container--not-visible': !person.active}" 
     [style.right]="stackItem(right)">
</div>
```

Notice that it is just referencing `right` and not `__person.right` since `right` is defined as a property of the component class, not of the person object.

If you need it to be unique for each person and not actually a global variable, then add the `right` property to the people objects.

Also, the hash (#) allows you to defined a `template reference variable` for the element it is attached to. So you have created a template reference variable for each of your divs that is called `__person`. This is referencing the div elements *not* the associated person objects.